# cronjob not running script inside another user bin folder

Tags: cron

I'm trying to have `root` run a script sitting inside another user's bin folder (say '`john`'). The script itself is owned by `root` and chmoded 774.

I can launch the script without any issue from the command line.
Via cron, it does not get started. I can't understand why.

Here is the content if i crontab -e while logged in as root.

```
# daily backup
15 2 * * * php -q /home/john/bin/backup
```

My server is a Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.5 (Santiago)

Comment: What is the group of the script?

Comment: @Kenny group is root, owner is root

Comment: How can crontab run the script if only root and the root group have executing permissions?

Comment: I don't get any "permission denied" issue, so I doubt that is the cause. I chmoded the script 0777 just in case.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps php is not in the default PATH, such as in /usr/local/bin rather than /usr/bin or /bin.

Always redirect the output of both stdout and stderr, otherwise the default has traditionally been to send a message via /usr/bin/mail, and you probably don't want to get an email each time the job runs.

When you revise your crontab (i.e. "`/usr/local/bin/php -q /home/john/bin/backup > /tmp/crontest.txt 2>&1`") you can then see if any error messages are being logged.

Comment: I tested using the full path to php and the short path with a simpler script, and both worked. So php is in the default path. I did follow your advise to dump any message to crontest.txt, I'll see tomorrow if it works.

Comment: When adding ` > /tmp/crontest.txt 2>&1` to the cronjob, the log file shows the entire content of the script, not the log messages i scripted. Is that normal?